# PHP - Creacion de tablas desde Base de Datos MYSQL

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

estoy desarrollando una consulta para poder extraer los datos de una BD a una tabla en PHP, mi pñroblema es que me muestra los datos pero se saltan en diferentes lineas, yo deseo que salga los resultados en una sola fila.

La consulta que estoy usando es:

```
class Buscadordeta
{
    private $busqueda=array();

    public function buscardeta()
    {
        //print_r($_GET);exit;
        $query = "SELECT D.codcon, A.MESINI,B.MESFIN, D.abrcon, C.des_corta, A.importe FROM plutimcp A
        inner join plmovmae B 
            on A.libele=B.libele and A.mesini=B.mesini
        inner join pltabmcp C
            on A.codcon=C.concepto
        inner join pltabcon D
            on C.codcon=D.codcon
        WHERE A.tipo BETWEEN 1 and 4 and B.nombre like '%".$_GET['s']."%'
        group by A.mesini, D.codcon 
        order by A.MESINI;";
        /*$res = mysql_query($query,Conectar::con() or die("Error en: $busqueda: " . mysql_error()));*/
        $res = mysql_query($query,Conectar::con()) or die("Error en: $query: " . mysql_error());
        while ($reg=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            $this->busqueda[] = $reg;
        }
            return $this->busqueda;
    }

}
```

Y para mostrar los datos el siguiente codigo

```
<table border="2">
<tr>
        <th width="50px">INICIO</th>
        <th width="50px">REM.BAS 1001</th>
        <th width="50px">R.REUNIF 1002</th>
        <th width="50px">BON.PER 1003</th>
        <th width="50px">BON.FAMI 1004</th>
        <th width="50px">TRA.HOMO 1005</th>
        <th width="50px">COST.VID 1006</th>
        <th width="50px">MOV.REF 1007</th>
        <th width="50px">BE051.91 1008</th>
        <th width="50px">10.23%+3 1009</th>
        <th width="50px">REM ANTE 1010 </th>
        <th width="50px">ICAJ3.3% 1011 </th>
        <th width="50px">A.J.SUP 1012</th>
        <th width="50px">DS040.92 1014</th>
        <th width="50px">DL.25671 1015</th>
        <th width="50px">DL.25697 1016</th>
        <th width="50px">BE.81.93 1017</th>
        <th width="50px">BE.19.94 1018</th>
        <th width="50px">DU.80.94 1019</th>
        <th width="50px">D.118.94 1020</th>
        <th width="50px">DU090.96 1021</th>
        <th width="50px">DU073/97 1022</th>
        <th width="50px">LEY25303 1023</th>
        <th width="50px">AS.COM.T 1024</th>
        <th width="50px">ART.18 1025</th>
        <th width="50px">PEN.PROV 1026</th>
        <th width="50px">PEN.DOC 1027</th>
        <th width="50px">PEN.GRA 1028</th>
        <th width="50px">FUN.SAL 1029</th>
        <th width="50px">DL.817 1030</th>
        <th width="50px">DU011/99 1031</th>
        <th width="50px">DU037.94 1038</th>
        <th width="50px">AGUINALD 1054</th>
        <th width="50px">REINTEGR 1160</th>
        <th width="200px">TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
<?php
//COMPROBAMOS SI HAY REGISTROS EN LA BUSQUEDA, SI NO LOS HAY, MOSATRAMOS UN MENSAJE DICIENDO QUE NO HAY RESULTADOS, EN OTRO CASO, MOSTRAMOS LOS RESULTADOS
if(count($buscamedeta)==0)
{
echo "<h2>No hay resultados para su búsqueda...</h2>";
}else{
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($buscamedeta);$i++)
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <?php echo $buscamedeta[$i]["MESINI"] ."/". $buscamedeta[$i]["MESFIN"]?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1001")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }

            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1002")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1003")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1004")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1005")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1006")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1007")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1008")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1009")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1010")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1011")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1012")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
          <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1014")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1015")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1016")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1017")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1018")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1019")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1020")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1021")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1022")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
       <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1023")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1024")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1025")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1026")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1027")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1028")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1029")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1030")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1031")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1038")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1054")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            if ($buscamedeta[$i]["codcon"]=="1160")
            {
            echo $buscamedeta[$i]["importe"];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
}
?>


</table>
```

Pero me muestra de la siguiente manera y deseo que todo sea en una sola fila relacionado por la columna inicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

el problema que tienes esta en la consulta sql trata de usar un group by a la operacion de este campo (A.MESINI/B.MESFIN) hazlo desde la consulta para que puedas agruparlos

```
SELECT D.codcon, (A.MESINI/B.MESFIN) as inicio, A.MESINI,B.MESFIN, D.abrcon, C.des_corta, A.importe FROM plutimcp A
        inner join plmovmae B 
            on A.libele=B.libele and A.mesini=B.mesini
        inner join pltabmcp C
            on A.codcon=C.concepto
        inner join pltabcon D
            on C.codcon=D.codcon
        WHERE A.tipo BETWEEN 1 and 4 and B.nombre like '%".$_GET['s']."%'
        group by A.mesini, D.codcon ,(A.MESINI/B.MESFIN),B.MESFIN
        order by A.MESINI;
```